# How to reduce sensitivity or jumpiness on a simple plane?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

I'm working on a web app for a museum and i'm using aframe and aframe-ar.
The behavior is:

- You see a marker and you point your phone to the marker.
- In the phone you can see a image as a texture of the plane
- You car move on x and y basis the object, and also you can rotate it.

It all works fine, i get the marker consistently and the posisitoning is really good, but the plane is very jumpy, it's like it thinks that I'm moving my hand very fast.
Anyway, i would appreciate very much if someone can help on how to resolve this issue.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just the nature of marker-based AR using phone camera all in JS without native libraries ARCore or ARKit. Try ARCore or ARKit browsers?